# How to delete files with exclamation marks! using emacs' delete-file

Tags: file, emacs

I'm trying to make emacs' `delete-file` function delete files with exclamation marks in their names.

The particular use case is that I have set emacs to save all backup files in a single directory and to delete old backup files. However, when all backup files are placed in one directory, the directory separator `/` is replaced with `!`.

When delete-file is called on a file with an exclamation mark in its name, it returns zero and the file is not deleted. It doesn't signal any error. Normally, delete-file returns nil. Anyway, emacs' backup system uses delete-file for deletion, and I'd rather not redefine the entire function just to change a single line.

I've tried backslashing the exclamation marks and shell-quoting the filename string, and neither has worked. I found out that something in my config is causing this, but I haven't figured out what yet. I have tracked the source of the problem to my custom `system-move-file-to-trash` function, which I now have to debug.

So, how can I make this work?

Emacs version:
GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1
emacs-snapshot:
  Installed: 1:20090730-1~jaunty1

Comment: Try using an official release of Emacs, perhaps the problem is in this intermediate build.

Comment: To anyone reading this, the problem is that you're not supposed to call `shell-quote-argument` on strings that you're passing to `call-process`. Apparently `call-process` bypasses the shell, so shell-quoting only creates problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. My custom `system-move-file-to-trash` function, which delete-file will automatically use, inappropriately called `shell-quote-argument` on the file name. Apparently arguments to a command run using `call-process` do *not* need to be shell-quoted.

Answer (score 4):

```
M-x delete-file
```

Then just enter the name of the file, don't escape anything, just the name,

```
!home!blah!filename
```

and it just works.  And the same goes for the lisp invocation,

```
(delete-file "!home!blah!filename")
```

Comment: Your observation that delete-file works interactively gave me the clue I needed. I suspect that one of my customizations broke completing-read in some subtle way, so that even when delete-file isn't prompting me for a file, it still breaks somehow.